# How to show characteristic polynomial = minimal polynomial in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

So I've got an $n\times n$ Matrix, $A$, such that it's $a$ on the diagonal and $1$ on the diagonal above the actual diagonal. I've shown the characteristic polynomial is $(x-a)^n$. I am asked to find its characteristic polynomial, playing around with smaller matrices I've got the feeling that the minimal polynomial is the same but can't prove it. Have tried to use induction but get stuck! Any help will be appreciated! (I get the minimal polynomial will be of the form $(x-a)^k$, where $k\in\{0,1,...,n\}$)

Comment: Hint: do a 2 by 2 example by hand, then a 3 by 3 example by hand. There is a pattern for the number you call $k.$ It's amazing!!

Comment: This is how I got the intuition that the two polynomials should be the same but I couldn't spot a pattern!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find a vector $v$ such that $(A-aI)^{n-1} v \ne 0$.

Comment: Would I be looking for a single vector for all n? Also, this would show that the powers less than $n-1$ are not zero would it?

Comment: Has to be a different vector for each $n$, because it's in $\mathbb R^n$.  But they all have a similar form.

Comment: I'm currently trying this method, but I am not sure what form $(A-aI)^{n-1}v $ takes so I'm finding it hard to find a $v$ for each n, any help?

Comment: Hint: what does $A-aI$ do to a vector that has only one nonzero entry?

Answer (score 1):

Show that $$(A-aI)e_k=e_{k-1}$$ where $e_i$ is the canonical basis.

Comment: I have been able to show this, but not sure how this leads to a proof of my question, unless I'm missing something?